# Doing Tabular Labels (Chemboxes)

Tags: labeling, software-recommendations, table, callout

I have a project manager who really wants "chemboxes", basically labels/callouts with tabular data.  I've been using an older vbscript labeling expression, but they want something that is more aesthetically pleasing. I also require that it be either feature linked or easily updated/replicated with new data, but I don't mind some manual arrangement for clearer labeling/layout (I just don't have time to create individual tables).

The only thing I've really found that might match their requirements is geoCallout (http://www.superiorinfotech.com/products.html) but I can't seem to find any reviews.

Does anyone have any experience with the geoCallout?